# react this.refs.variable.value returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, undefined, redux

Here is my react code, very basic from bucky's tutorial

```
renderForm: function(){
            return (
                <div className = "commentContainer">
                    <textarea ref = "hola" defaultValue={this.props.children}></textarea>
                    <button onClick={this.save} className = "button-success">Save</button>
                </div>
            );
        },
```

In renderFomr function, there is a textarea which I gave ref value to "hola" and I have onclick event to a function called save

```
  save: function (){
    var val = this.refs.hola.value;
    console.log(val);
    this.setState({editing: false});
    this.props.updateCommentText(val, this.props.index);
  },
```

However, in this save function when I set the value of variable "val" by writing this.refs.hola.value and test it in the logs, it gives me "undefined".

I'm thinking maybe it's the version problem?

these are the cdns i use

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Anybody knows why?

Comment: [<textarea>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) do not have a *value* property

Comment: try to console only this.refs.hola,check element getting or not

Comment: Consider reading through the docs for refs at https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html. It explains it pretty well, including the switch to callback refs instead of string refs. If this is real code and not just for practise, you should also read about react controlled/uncontrolled components: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html